# On click change class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am just working on a project and now I need a little bit of help.

`When the user enters the site they are gonna see this image`

[image]

And

`on mouse over this is gonna show`

[image]

When the user clicks the play button the music should now it works fine. But it should change to pause button instead of the play button and also the image should stay with the second image and with a pause button.

```html
<div class="pos-rlt">
  <div class="bottom"> <span class="badge bg-info m-l-sm m-b-sm">04:08</span> 
  </div>
  <div class="item-overlay opacity r r-2x bg-black">
    <div class="text-info padder m-t-sm text-sm"> <i class="fa fa-star"></i>  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>  <i class="fa fa-star"></i>  <i class="fa fa-star-o text-muted"></i> 
    </div>
    <div class="center text-center m-t-n"> <a href="#"><i data-jp-src="songs/18.mp3" class="icon-control-play i-2x"></i></a> 
    </div>
    <div class="bottom padder m-b-sm">
      <a href="#" class="pull-right"> <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> 
      </a>
      <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> 
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="images/p1.jpg" alt="" class="r r-2x img-full">
  </a>
</div>
```

The class of first image is:

```
item-overlay opacity r r-2x bg-black
```

and the second image:

```
item-overlay opacity r r-2x bg-black active
```

and class of play button is

```
class="icon-control-play i-2x
```

and of the pause button is

```
icon-control-pause i-2x text-active
```

What I want is when users click the play button
`class="icon-control-play i-2x`. It should change the class of play button to `icon-control-pause i-2x text-active` and the class of image `item-overlay opacity r r-2x bg-black` also should change to `item-overlay opacity r r-2x bg-black active`. And when the user again clicks that it should reverse.

With Regards

Nai

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle classes with toggleClass ;

```
$(".icon-control-play i-2x").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('.icon-control-pause i-2x text-active').toggleClass('.icon-control-play i-2x');
)};
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it

Comment: This should work fine anywhere in your existing jquery code. Or in a script tag as long as you have jquery called previously.